# How to increase the hash rate on 1050ti 12 gpu

Tags: mining, gpu

As i am new in this i have setup my 12 gpu for ethermining i am using simplemining Os i tried to push the hashrate through overclocking but its only 14.81 M/h which very disappointing could you please help me to increase it

Comment: http://1stminingrig.com/nvidia-geforce-gtx-1050-1050ti-mining-performance-review/ suggests that that is a normal speed for the 1050ti. Did you read something that led you to believe something else? Also, based on the price of the card and my Nash equilibrium calculations for rational actors choosing to mine vs. buy ether on the open market, I would expect that to be around the upper limit for hash rate.